# Strange noise in headphones when no sound is played

Tags: sound, 14.04, headphones, noise

There is a strange noise from my headphones on Lenovo T440. The sound is like when you tune your radio, but you get a wrong frequency and you hear unpleasant noise. The noise starts when Ubuntu 14.04 boots up and ends after a shutdown. It is coming out only through my headphones, there is no noise through the speakers.

The strange thing is that the noise disappears when any sound is played or if I enter sound preferences. But when a sound is stopped, it appears again after 10 seconds or less. Also, the noise goes way down (or maybe even disappears) if I put in my laptop charger and stop the music.

No matter how I change my volume level, the noise level is the same. It seems like the output is not disabled after sound stops.

```
sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC292 Analog [ALC292 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: im on the lenovo t440s and this issue recently occured with my setup on 14.04 as well. as unrelated as it seems, my hunch is that it happened after I altered some /etc/x11/ mouse related settings and then restarted lightdm. was never an issue in the past and now its pervasive.

Comment: The problem was gone after I changed the `beep` channel in `alsamixer` from `0` to something else and back to `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The bad old Noise issue in the headphones on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/860109/the-bad-old-noise-issue-in-the-headphones-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: reversing direction (voting to leave this open) as this post has more answers views and votes

Answer (score 43):

Got the same problem on Dell XPS15 (9550, 2015 model in Xenial). Solved it in alsamixer and muting the *loopback* channel.

```
$ alsamixer
```

Navigating to `loopback` (all the way to the right, with `→` key) and setting it to `Disabled` using the `↑` key.

- No reboot needed;
- No root needed;
- Is permanent as far as I noticed.

Comment: This solution worked on my Dell Precision 5510.

Comment: This worked on my Dell Precision 5510 as well. Thank you!

Comment: This works perfectly on Dell

Comment: Works on Lenovo y700. I had issue with the noise issue with the speakers not head phone. The audio_power save method does not work in my case

Comment: With this method, you can also keep the powersave on, and thus save battery.

Comment: Worked very well on my HP ZBook 15 G2

Comment: My looback is already set as Disabled by default ):

Comment: This also worked for my Thinkpad X1 Carbon (3rd gen)!

Comment: Finally! this worked on HP Spectre x360, and ubuntu 18.04, however the option that I disabled was called 'Auto-Mute'.

Comment: I changed 'Headphone Mic Boost' to 10 (one up) and somehow solved. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/7pjdnf/xps_13_9360_ubuntu_hissing_sound/) I also found someone suggesting it. (Dell XPS 13 9360)

Comment: There is no "Loopback" option on mine. Dell XPS 7390 w/ 20.04. The Headphone Mic Boost option also did nothing. Disabling Powersave (described by kvcx) worked, but would love to find a better option if this hurts battery life.

Comment: I cannot find the `loopback` option. Which "Sound Card" should I select?

Comment: My loopback was set to disabled but turning it on and off and just randomly playing with the other settings and then closing alsamixer and then again running alsamixer and then disabling loopback again and pressing the enter key, worked @.@ but then after a while the pitched noise came back again...

Comment: <Auto-Mut> did fix my ubuntu 22.

Answer (score 42):

It's possibly your audio interface going into power save.

If following commands clear the issue until you reboot or change the power supply it has got something to do with power save:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

Comment: Thanks! This one works on other distros ;-) 
I ended up having something like "options snd_hda_intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=0" in my modprobe.conf...

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, Xenial on Dell Inspiron 14 7000

Comment: Continues to work with 18.04 LTS (bionic).

Comment: worked for me on Fedora 28 on a Dell Precision 5520

Comment: worked for me, kubuntu

Comment: It still works on Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you.

Comment: It worked for me on Kubuntu 20.10 ... how can I make this permanent?

Comment: Same here on Kubuntu 20.10 dell inspiron 7537! Dude, you made my day.

Comment: it worker for me on kali linux 2021.1

Comment: but the issue is that when i restart the computer the problem again come and i have to again write the code

Comment: this also works in ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.17

Comment: Worked for me using Ubuntu 22.04 with Dell Precision M4800. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem on Dell Inspiron 3542 running Ubuntu 14.04.2

The problems appears to be in the audio powersave feature.

The noise stops when I open the sound settings, or when I play audio/video. The noise starts again when I stop playing audio/video and close sound settings.

This solution worked for me:
Edit the file

```
$ sudo nano /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave
```

change the line

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
```

to

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
```

Reboot.

I faced no further noise after this.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, Xenial on Dell XPS 13 9350

Comment: any ideas why power save is causing these strange noises? Isn't power save a good thing. I'm just curious!

Comment: sudo aplay -l gives me a similar output. I am using Dell Inspiron 15 3542. I don't have "intel-audio-powersave" file. Can I create one?

Comment: Possibly you need to select correct sound card by using F6 first

Comment: You are soooo awesome!!! Worked on my Macbook 2006 Late running only Ubuntu 16.04 LTS :)

Comment: I don't have such a file either on my Kubuntu 20.10. Can I create it? @Alex0007 what do you mean I have to select the correct card first? In which application I have to press F6?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.
I believe it is the noise that your microphone picks up.

Go into `Sound Settings`, under the `Input` tab, check `Mute` box near `Settings for <microphone_name> Microphone` (Not the `Mute` checkbox at the top).

[image]

That should do the trick.

Comment: Following your instruction, my headphone is mute.

Comment: For me on a Dell M3800, that had no effect.

Comment: the microphone does not typically play over the speakers unless you run `pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1`

Comment: This worked for me. Muting the microphone removed all the noise. Thank you.

Comment: This worked. Can someone explain why this works??

Comment: Selecting the headset as input device did it for me, it wasn't default!

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact the same problem and none of above method worked for me.

My laptop is ASUS ROG-G501JW and the sound card is Realtek.

I found the solution in this thread: [White and hissing noise in headphones, not present in Windows](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2312163).

Setting this line in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` fixed all of my problems:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

Comment: Confirmed on ASUS ROG-G501VW

Comment: This didn´t work for me with Dell M4800 Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have tlp activated?

If so edit /etc/default/tlp
and set the power save option values to 0

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0
```

this did the trick for me

Comment: On my Dell M3800, I tried setting `SOUND_POWER_SAVE=0`, but it didn't help...

Comment: For me, setting these values to 1 helped.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar problem on 19.10, and this is what fixed it for me. In my case, the hum was present when I plugged my stereo deck into the laptop, but *not* when I plugged in headphones.

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and `/etc/pulse/system.pa`, comment the following line:

```
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

Or try to create the file `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` with the lines:

```
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa
.nofail
unload-module module-suspend-on-idle
.fail
```

Sources:
[Static noise when NO audio playing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337064/static-noise-when-no-audio-playing/1408334),
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Pops_when_starting_and_stopping_playback

Comment: Worked for me using Ubuntu 22.04 with Dell Precision M4800. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this thread because I had the fuzzy earphones as well, but because of a different reason.

I have a USB fan plugged into my laptop and whilst it's turned on, I hear the fuzz on my earphones, so check if there are any devices on your USB ports causing the interference on your sound before testing the software fixes.

Comment: Why, why does this happen? As I read your answer, I noticed I didn't have my mouse plugged in before when I was listening to music and I did now. Disconnected it, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Kubuntu 18.04 and I solved by following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797013/ubuntu-16-04-constant-noise-problem-with-headphones?noredirect=1&lq=1), changing "Front Mic Boost" value from "dB gain 0,00, 0,00" to "dB gain 10,00, 10,00"

Comment: Worked for me using Ubuntu 22.04 with Dell Precision M4800. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem on Dell 3542 with Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME and it started happening after I installed TLP for power saving.
So after I saw here that the problem is related to power saving I simply uninstalled TLP and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Asus X200ca with ElementaryOS Loki (Ubuntu 16.04) and other linux distro that I had used. I fixed issue with

- run `alsamixer` (not in sudo mode)
- Navigate to `Auto-mute Mode` (using right arrow)
- Change it to enable (using up arrow)

Now I don't have the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

I found an unusual cause for my excessive background noise...  my Civilization 5 (run via Steam) was not exiting properly.  The background noise I was hearing was from the game.  I used "htop" to find and kill all Civilization processes and sure enough, the noise decreased every time I killed off a process from the game.

So not an Ubuntu nor audio problem; it was in fact one particular app (that never exits right anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I had dell too, the same problem. No one cli-command no help me(.
I try tuning alsamixer. option **Headphone M**
see screenshot

```
$ > alsamixer
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

If this is due to the **persistent battery mode of TLP** then the solution is easy.

First, check if this is the case. Run `sudo tlp-stat -s`, if this shows  `Mode = battery (persistent)`, then that's the cause of it.

The **Fix** is simple. Infact it was pointed out by @Foxtour in one of the answers.

1. Create a new file `/etc/tlp.d/95-YOUR-NAME.conf` and add the following content

   ```
   TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC
   TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=0
   ```
2. Restart `tlp`

   ```
   sudo service tlp restart
   ```

### Background

I am using ubuntu 20.04. I have never configured TLP and the Dell laptop has a freshly installed Ubuntu. This happened due to these 2 config options added in `/etc/tlp.d/50-estar-default.conf`.

```
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=BAT
TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=1
```

This means, the default mode is battery and this will be persistent all that time. It doesn't change even if you are on AC.

This configuration option was added by package `oem-fix-misc-cnl-tlp-estar-conf`.  The `apt-cache show oem-fix-misc-cnl-tlp-estar-conf` shows this description

```
Description: customized configuration for tlp.
 This package carrys agressive policy to pass energy-star, and also some blacklist for problematic devices.
```

Now you know why this happened

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem, but for me the solution was to lower the volume of the headset from the physical buttons on it.

If your headset has physical volume down buttons, turn the volume down using them. I guess the volume was so high it was transmitting the Bluetooth signals into noise.

Answer (score 0):

For Asus G551VW the above steps did not work for me. In this [article](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Soundkarten_konfigurieren/HDA/) you will find correct steps to install alsa & give it correct model name to use while communicating with the sound chip. For G551VW it was alc668-headset.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for any **fedora** users out there is to change the values in the following files:

`/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save`
`/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller`

You can use nano to open these files and replace **1 with 0** and **Y with N**, respectively.

Worked on my **Dell M2800** Laptop.

Comment: Since this is a Ubuntu only site how does this answer for a non Ubuntu OS apply?