# Ubuntu 16.04 constant noise problem with headphones

Tags: 16.04, dell, headphones, xps, noise

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on my xps 13, it is working fine except this problem. When I plug headphones in then a constant noise starting and never go until plug headphones out. I read about this problem and tried all of the solutions in [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457910/strange-noise-in-headphones-when-no-sound-is-played) and turned auto-mute mode off in alsamixer but nothing has changed.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which solutions have you tried? We wouldn't want to waste our time suggesting something that won't be helpful to you. It would be great if you could edit your question to include this information

Comment: I edit my question. I tried every solution in the topic and searched further solutions but they are related to older kernels so I didn't imply them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly this same problem with my XPS 13 and found a solutions here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/4j1zz4/headphones_have_static_noise_with_ubuntu_1604_on/

Essentially you need to do the following:
Start up alsamixer, then turn "Headphone Mic Boost" (that's the third control from the left for me) from "[dB gain: 0,00, 0,00]" one step up to "[dB gain: 10,00, 10,00]".

Comment: I am grateful to you!

Comment: Worked for me using Ubuntu 22.04 with Dell Precision M4800, actually any mic may work non muted and with non-zero level, so i used 1%. Thank you.