# Ubuntu 16.04 slight hissing / white noise in the headphones

Tags: sound, headphones

There is a slight hissing sound / noise in my headphones (3.5 jack) continuously.

It used to be really bad but since I disabled `loopback` in the alsamixer it's much better.

Are there any obvious fixes that I should try to get rid of any stand-by noises?

I have no microphone connected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Asus UX501 laptop. Solved it by turning off the Intel Audio Powersave as seen in : [Strange noise in headphones when no sound is played](https://askubuntu.com/a/614108/632293)

After replacing the location of the file, my terminal command looked like this:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave
```

then I changed the line

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
```

to

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
```

After a reboot my issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of users are facing noise problem when headphones are connected There are a lot of solutions given on Ask Ubuntu but none have worked for me.

I didn't have this problem when I used Windows 8.1, but I don't want to go back to Windows.

I have accepted the fact that my laptop's sound system is not shielded properly.

I haven't addressed the root of the problem, but just kind of made it a virtually unnoticable.

So, the hack is quite simple. As the problem persists only when there is no playback, I came up with a hack to always have a playback!

Now, this should be true only when the headphones are connected. And the playback should stop when headphones are removed.

Follow these simple steps:

**Step #1:** Install mplayer and configure it.

```
sudo apt install mplayer    
nano ~/.mplayer/config
```

type in that file

```
lirc=no
```

save and exit.

**Step #2:** Download this mp3 file [silence-10sec.mp3](http://www.jetcityorange.com/silent-ringtone/silence-10sec.mp3).

**Step #3:** Create a folder in home directory and name it `.hush`
Copy the mp3 file in your `.hush` directory

```
cp ~/Downloads/silence-10sec.mp3 ~/.hush/
```

In that folder, create a script file and name it `silence.sh`
Copy paste this code in the script file.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

plugged="jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug"
unplugged="jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug"

acpi_listen | while IFS= read -r event;
do
    if [ "$event" == "$plugged" ]
    then
       mplayer -really-quiet -loop 0 ~/.scripts/silence-10sec.mp3 &
    elif [ "$event" == "$unplugged" ]
    then
       pkill -f mplayer
    fi
done
```

Make it executable with the command `chmod +755 silence.sh`

**Step #4:** Type `startup applications` in the Dash and add the path of `silence.sh` script to it.

[image: Startup applications dialog]

So, basically what we are doing is listening to events of headphones being connected and disconnected and playing or stopping the blank mp3 file in a loop. Now, I have used `mplayer` because I know that I am never gonna use that for any other purpose and killing its process is completely safe for me.

I came  up with this idea when [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg) answered  [one of my questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879139/using-acpi-listen-command-in-a-shell-script).

He came up with this script and I just made modifications to it to suit the requirement.

Comment: Is this still your solution today or have you managed to address the root problem?

Comment: I am no longer running the script as the problem has been resolved since i upgraded to 16.04.2.

Comment: I can only hope they fix it for XPS 9370 soon...

Comment: Yup. You can use this as a workaround until then. Give a +1 if this helps.

Comment: I've not used the fix as playing a silent mp3 doesn't sit well with me. Plus, I've not had time to tune power usage yet so this will be additional drain on an already limited battery time...

Comment: You are on 16.04? I would recommend you to switch to 18.04.1. It's quite good when it comes to battery life. I did a minimal install so no bloatware. All light and nice. Gives upto 6 hours of battery life. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I'm on 18.04 but I'm coming from a mac. The battery life is shocking in comparison.