# Using acpi_listen command in a shell script

Tags: bash, sound, scripts, headphones, acpi

I am on UBuntu 16.04. I have asked a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877804/notify-send-on-headphones-plugged) regarding headphones plug unplug event. What I tried didn't work.  I want to use **acpi_listen** command to listen to headphones connected event and display a message using notify-send. How to use acpi_listen in a *shell script*?

Comment: I think `udev` makes more sense than `acpi_listen` but you may find this thread interesting with many different answers for headphone control: http://askubuntu.com/questions/769593/16-04-headphones-detected-but-not-switched-on-automatically-after-startup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing script like that is fairly simple - you need to pipe `acpi_listen` to `while IFS= read -r line ; do ... done` structure, and take care of handling the events within that structure. The `read` shell builtin command will wait for a line of text from `acpi_listen` and processing will occur when the `if` statement  sees that the line contains appropriate text. Alternatively, one could use `case` statement for better portability of the script.

Here's the simple script I personally would use. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
#!/bin/bash
acpi_listen | while IFS= read -r line;
do
    if [ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug" ]
    then
       notify-send "headphones connected"
       sleep 1.5 && killall notify-osd
    elif [ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug" ]
    then
       notify-send "headphones disconnected"
       sleep 1.5 && killall notify-osd
    fi
done
```

Note that if you plan to run this from cron job or via `/etc/rc.local`, you would need to export your `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` for `notify-send` to work.

Comment: Simply elegant! Thanks a lot Serg. You have been helping me since I have migrated to Ubuntu. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1. I read your **edit** comments on POSIX. So I have to change all my `==` to `=` now?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix If you're working only with `bash` and Ubuntu, then it's OK, no need to change anything. When you work with multiple OS and rely on POSIX  `/bin/sh` then it'd better be POSIX compliant. Choice here is also because of `[`.  When you use `[[` and `==`, the stuff on the right is treated as regex pattern. You kinda have to be aware of that of there's special characters you're trying to match, like `*` and  `^`. Pattern vs literal string, in other words

Comment: Serge, it's kind of over my head but I only use `#!/bin/bash` and read single `[` invokes `test` external command so I've been converting stuff to `[[` built-in. As far as regex goes, Muru would be the first to tell you it gives me a headache :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The `[` and `[[` are tools, and you need right tool for the right job.  If you are dealing with simple string comparison, `[` is enough. But `[[` is more powerful, and when you need that extra pattern matching power in shell scripts, `[[` will be your friend.  Compare `[ "mystring" == *str* ]` and `[[ "mystring" == *str* ]]`. When you have `bash`, this is your pattern matching friend. Otherwise, if you only have `/bin/sh` you may need  complex `case`  statement.

Comment: Compare also `( set -x ;[ *.txt  == *txt ] && echo "Yes" )` vs `( set -x ;[[ *.txt  == *txt ]] && echo "Yes" )` The `[[` won't perform filename globbing where you don't want it, i.e. when you are doing pattern and string comparison matching on variable, you don't want `*` behave as file glob. There are better utilities for that already anyway, like `find`.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar, but instead of a notification, I wanted to pause when unplugged (and the music was playing) and play when plugged in (and the music was paused).

I know, this is not *exactly* what the OP asked for, but I can’t comment here (what a pity that Stack Exchange sites don’t accumulate reputation score each other).

Anyway, here’s modified script of the @Sergiy’s one. I don’t say it is optimised or whatever, but it is working. I would be glad if someone (a Basher Pro? ;p) would improve it. :)

<strike>Btw, I tried using it with `vlc` (or `cvlc`, `nvlc`), but I couldn’t find a way to toggle play/pause from terminal when `vlc` was running in background (what I do all the time).</strike>

And note that I use `audacious` player—if you use whatever else, you need to change `$state` variable and playing/pausing commands.

**UPDATE**
Added control for vlc (based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43156436/3408342) answer, as @BenjaminR has pointed out).

```bsh
# Play/pause music like in smartphones

# Play when the headphone was plugged in,
# pause when the headphone was unplugged

# As there is no separate option in Audacious
# for playing even if it is already playing
# (or for pausing even if it is already paused),
# only toggles (e.g. play when paused, otherwise pause),
# I was forced to check the state of playback
# from PulseAudio (using `pacmd`).

# Added control for vlc (src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43156436/3408342)

#!/bin/bash
acpi_listen | while IFS= read -r line; do
    test=$(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep "application.process.binary\|state" | \sed 's/[="]//g' - | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ $test ]]; then
        stateAud=$(echo "$test" | grep audacious -B1 | head -1)
        stateVlc=$(echo "$test" | grep vlc -B1 | head -1)

        # Play music when headphone jack has been plugged in AND the stateAud is corked/paused
        if [[ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug" && $stateAud = "CORKED" ]]; then
            audacious -t
        fi
        if [[ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug" && $stateVlc = "CORKED" ]]; then
            dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Play
        fi
        if [[ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug" && $stateAud = "RUNNING" ]]; then
            audacious -t
        fi
        if [[ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug" && $stateVlc = "RUNNING" ]]; then
            dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause
        fi
        echo
    fi
done
```

Comment: So this works for `audacious`, but not for VLC? Is that what you're saying?
nb. Once you've got > 200 reputation in one site, you will automatically get 100 reputation on any new SE site you join as a "trusted" user. Ref: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79783

Comment: @BenjaminR, I _would_ work with `vlc` _if_ `vlc` would have a _command-line_ option to toggle play/pause (e.g. `vlc --pause`). However, I could not find one in `vlc --help`. Or you know a way around it? I’m interested. :)

And thank you for info about the reputation. I am just a occasional user of these sites—I search more than I ask (as I believe that _‘everything’ is on the Web_).

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256193/linux-control-a-running-vlc-process-through-command-line