# Static noise when NO audio playing

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, noise

I have this issue where I hear a static noise coming from my speakers that goes away when I start playing any audio and comes back after a few seconds when I am not playing any audio.

Answer (score 11):

Following [these](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Getting_debug_output_from_pulseaudio) instructions, I ran pulseaudio in verbose mode:

```
$ systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
$ systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
$ pulseaudio -v
```

And I found the following output each time the static noise started:

```
I: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Source alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_Wireless_Headset_88C626977831-00.multichannel-input idle for too long, suspending ...
I: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-source.c: Device suspended...
I: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.6.analog-stereo idle for too long, suspending ...
I: [alsa-sink-ALC887-VD Analog] alsa-sink.c: Device suspended...
I: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.1.hdmi-stereo idle for too long, suspending ...
I: [alsa-sink-HDMI 0] alsa-sink.c: Device suspended...
I: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_Wireless_Headset_88C626977831-00.analog-stereo idle for too long, suspending ...
I: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-sink.c: Device suspended...
```

Then, I commented out this line from `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
### load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

Finally, I reboot my computer and the static noise was gone :)

Comment: On behalf of user @BlackThorne: "I didn't have a static noise, I had a pulse-like waveform audio, but same behavior, similar output in verbose, solved using this answer".

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the audio going into power-save mode. There are two ways that I know of to work around the issue:

1. Disable audio power-save for pulseaudio by editing the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, and comment out the line

```
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

You can comment a line by prepending a '`#`' to the beginning of the line.
This seems to be the most popular solution, as I found it in many places including Fabian's answer.

2. Disable power save for the audio device system-wide by running the command

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

This solution I found at https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-static-noise-from-speakers-linux/.

At the end of the day, I don't think it matters how you workaround the issue. Personally, I prefer the second option because it is more general as it does not depend on pulseaudio.

Comment: `snd_hda_intel` - that seems hardware-specific? Is it possible that for some people with different audio hardware, and accordingly, a different driver / module, this measure wouldn't work?

Comment: It might be hardware-specific, but I wouldn't know. From the link I shared, there was no indication that it is hardware-specific. In any case, it worked for me, so I figured I would share it.