# Make these 2 commands run every time my ubuntu starts

Tags: command-line, sound, scripts, headphones

I have these 2 commands

```bsh
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

which are used to remove sound from headphones when no video is being played. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457910/strange-noise-in-headphones-when-no-sound-is-played)

Now instead of running these 2 commands every time, can I do something like when ever I want to run, I just 1 click on something and it runs or it auto runs every time my ubuntu starts. Thanks.

I have 20.04

Comment: You also could do that using crontab.

Answer (score 1):

To accommodate both requirements, you can create an executable shell script that can be executed via the command line or a double-click as well as something that is run at startup.

#### 1 — Create a Shell Script

First, put the commands into a shell script. For example, in `/home/{user}/iGotThePower.sh` (do change the name if you'd like something more appropriate):

```py
#!/bin/bash

echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

Be sure to replace `{user}` with your home directory name.

#### 2 — Create a `systemd` service

Next, you'll need to create a file at `/etc/systemd/system/iGotsPower.service` (again, you can change this name):

```
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/{user}/iGotThePower.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

#### 3 — Set Permissions

We'll need to make sure the permissions are correct:

```
$ sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/iGotsPower.service
$ sudo chmod 744 /home/{user}/iGotThePower.sh
$ sudo chmod +x /home/{user}/iGotThePower.sh
```

#### 4 — Enable the Service Unit

Now that the basics are in place, we can enable the new service:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable iGotsPower.service
```

#### 5 — Test with a Reboot

Now that all the core elements are in place, you can test this by rebooting. Double-clicking on the `iGotThePower.sh` file should also execute the script whenever you would like to have it run. Alternatively, you can open a terminal and type `./iGotThePower.sh` to execute the two lines within.

Hope this gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @Matigo, I'm not OP, but please could you help me with how one can find a different candidate for `After=`? I tried to run xrandr commands at startup (to modify display gamma), but I'm guessing they were being executed too early, therefore were being reset by the windowing system or something else. Could you please give advice on how one can "shop around" for and identify the right event for `After=`?