# Theres static noise in my wired headphone always when connected to ubuntu 23.04

Tags: headphones

Hello I have a dell inspiron 3542 and when I connect my wired headphones I always hear static noise it is driving me crazy this problem never happened in Windows 10,8,7 ever

Output of

```
shubhang@shubhang:~$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-20-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
shubhang@shubhang:~$
```

And i am using tribit xfree go headset

Comment: Is your microphone muted? (either your laptop's inbuild or any other mic)

Comment: yep my mic is meted

Comment: do you have any solution please help me man its damn irrittating @kanehekili

Comment: No solution, since I don't have any information. If you hear a noise, you should check pulseaudio (you didn't tell me if you have installed it or pipewire) or  ALSA (of which I do not know if you have it installed either). There must be a source that generates this sound. You should install `pavucontrol`and check your sources or read the manual on how to check it with the commandline `pactl` .

Comment: As a second thought you should try to delete `~/.config/pulse` - if it exists. You could add the output of `inxi -A` to your question, just to get a little more information about your system

Comment: look i installed ubuntu 23.04 freshly just so i didn't install anything now can you tell me solution, i dont why people are hating this question and downvoting and voting to close?? @kanehekili

Comment: Sorry, I asked you to provide information, you did not. Your tone is hostile, so I'm not inclined to dig in further

Comment: i am sorry about my tone i am not native i dont meant to be rude @kanehekili, and i provide you info that i didn't installed anything its just a new copy of ubuntu as it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146474/discussion-between-imposter-and-kanehekili).

Comment: What is the make/model of wired headphones that you're using? Also, as @kanehekili already mentioned, please edit your question to include the output of `inxi -A` (you will likely have to install this package first).

Comment: see @richbl i edit my question,

Comment: and i also did the pavucontrol thingy and my input is totally of like there are 3 mics showing and they are at zero @richbl

Comment: @imposter, beyond checking channels through `pavucontrol` have you done any additional diagnostics? You might want to review the [following (older) AU question](https://askubuntu.com/q/457910/32664), as it may provide some useful actions to help put some additional context around your specific issue.

Comment: @richbl yeah i tried these but they are not working :(

Comment: Check if there is any EMI interference. For example, is the charger running nearby? For microphones with no isolation, that is an issue.

Comment: how to check plz tell pls @AnonymousGuy

Comment: @imposter Edited the OG comment. EMI stands for electromagnetic interference (yeah EMI interference is redundant, like AC current).

Comment: no man theres nothing just my laptop is okugged in that's it @AnonymousGuy

Comment: @imposter Unplug it and check.

Comment: @AnonymousGuy no nothing but even if that's the caase then why windows 10 never give me any sort of problem?

Comment: Is `suspend-mode` uncommented in `/usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/media-session.conf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already tested that the hardware is not broken by running the system with another OS, you can probably fix the issue by adjusting hardware mixer settings. I prefer to use `alsamixer` for this because it has all the settings even though the UI is a bit weird.

Basically open a terminal, run `alsamixer` (if that's missing, you can install it with command `sudo apt install alsa-utils`).

Once the `alsamixer` has started, press `F6` to select the soundcard your headphones are connected to, the press `F5` to make all channels and settings visible and start adjusting channels one by one until you hear a change in the noise.

For every channel you can use key `M` to toggle mute, `space` to switch capture source and up arrow / down arrow to adjust the channel volume or enable/disable feature. The capture flag is supposed to select only the recording source(s) but some audio hardware has weird interlinked limitations between input and output channels and changing the recording sources may affect the sound output, too.

It's a good idea to restore the same settings for each channel if that channel doesn't seem to affect the problem you're experiencing.

Some features and channel names will have cryptic values because most Linux audio drivers have been created via reverse engineering and officially marketed names are typically not known to the device driver developers.

I'd guess your problem is that some analog input source is not muted but the only way to figure it out is to try one-by-one until you find the culprit.

You can exit `alsamixer` by pressing `ESC`.

When you shutdown your system normally, the current hardware state should be stored and restored during next boot so you should only need to do this once.

Other people may recommend using `pavucontrol` but that doesn't adjust the hardware directly but via pulseaudio API which may hide some settings that `alsamixer` can adjust. If you think `alsamixer` is too hard to use, you can try with `pavucontrol` first, if you find that that easier to use. In most cases the `pavucontrol` is good enough.

(Also note that if your audio device is based on Intel HDA chipset, it supports reconfiguring the chip to use any soldered plug as input and output as you wish. In theory, it's possible to configure the chipset (accidentally) so that it uses any physical connector as microphone source, no matter what the hardware says near the connector or in the end user manual.)

And if your audio setup is totally messed up, you could try removing `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` after booting from USB memory stick to make sure the previously stored hardware configuration is not messing things up. That file contains (in both machine and human readable format) the current settings of the hardware at the last system shutdown.

Comment: brother there is nothing like alsamixer it says cant locate package alsamixer?

Comment: My bad, the package is called `alsa-utils` and the binary `alsamixer` is included in that package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/alsa-utils – I'll fix the answer.

Comment: it is not working man, i dont think there is a solution but thanks for helping anyway

Comment: i will try now some other linux distro or try to isntall windows 7 cuz 10 hangs too much, cuz this problem in ubuntu is just too irritating and i cant live without headphone cuz of work so yeah thanks man, i think this is where my ubuntu journey ends.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if it does not work? Of course it will not work, it assumed legacy pulseaudio/alsa setup instead of pipewire.

Comment: idk what u mean by legacy pulseadio...... can you explain to me like in simple term cuz i am noob

Comment: @AnonymousGuy You're right that *if* the hardware has PipeWire specific drivers, then the above will not have direct hardware control. However, not all hardware has native PipeWire drivers and in that case device drivers designed for ALSA will be used as a fallback, if I've understood correctly. For that case, `alsamixer` should be able to control all hardware features. Unfortunately, I don't know how to check if your device has native drivers or not.

Comment: If Windows 10 hangs on your hardware during normal use, you probably have some hardware issue that should be sorted out no matter what OS you use. Typical cause for hard hangs are memory errors or CPU errors. And the root cause for those errors is often power delivery: bad PSU or bad voltage control on motherboard. For example, my desktop machine is unstable (hangs randomly around once per week) if I have `auto` selected for CPU voltage but if I use fixed voltage at 1.1 V, it's totally solid (not a single hang since I changed the CPU voltage in BIOS a couple of months ago!).

Comment: For details about how PipeWire uses the actual hardware, see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/FAQ#pipewire-buffering-explained